# Android NDK gives this error make Error 2

Tags: android, android-ndk

Im trying to build android NDK and it gives me this error.
Im using eclipse. 
Im using android-ndk-r12. and the Android NDK Preference in eclipse is C:\android-ndk-r12 (I have tried "C:\android-ndk-r12\build" too and it did not work). And the android Android.mk is as below:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := com_example_ndktest_Store
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_example_ndktest_Store.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The error is as below:

```
[armeabi-v7a] "Compile++ arm  ": "com_example_ndktesting_Store <= com_example_ndktesting_Store.cpp"
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, C:/android-ndk-r12/build//../toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++.exe -MMD -MP -MF ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/com_example_ndktesting_Store/com_example_ndktesting_Store.o.d -gcc-toolchain C:/android-ndk-r12/build//../toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-invalid-command-line-argument -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -no-canonical-prefixes -fno-integrated-as -g -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -marm -O2 -DNDEBUG -IC:/android-ndk-r12/build//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -IC:/android-ndk-r12/build//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a/include -IC:/android-ndk-r12/build//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/backward -Ijni -DANDROID -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=softfp -fno-short-enums -Werror -DANDROID -DDISABLE_IMPORTGL -isystem /usr/include/ -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -std=gnu++0x -frtti -fexceptions -DANDROID -isystem C:/android-ndk-r12/build//../platforms/android-24/arch-arm/usr/include -c jni/com_example_ndktesting_Store.cpp -o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/com_example_ndktesting_Store/com_example_ndktesting_Store.o, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/com_example_ndktesting_Store/com_example_ndktesting_Store.o] Error 2
```

Comment: Judging by the error message, it looks like your path to the compiler executable is incorrect. Have you double-checked it?

Comment: @zenzelezz I have edited my question. please help me if you can.

Comment: If you open a Windows command prompt and type `C:/android-ndk-r12/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++.exe`, does that also give an error?

Comment: after prebuilt, there is no "windows-x86_64" folder. although there is a "windows" folder. and if i change "windows-x86_64" in the code above to "windows" it will give me this error: clang++.exe: error: no input files

Comment: Does Eclipse perhaps have a setting somewhere where you can specify exactly which compiler toolchain to use?

Comment: Yes there is. When you click on the properties of project. in C/C++ Builder-> Tool Chain Editor. what should i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1- Make Sure you have the right version of NDK :**
If you use 32bit Windows, you should download and install android-ndk-r12-windows-x86.zip and if you use 64bit Windows, you should download and install android-ndk-r12-windows-x86_64.zip

**2- Define proper toolchain:** 
are you sure clang++.exe is found in the specified path , dose this ndk version has this toolchain?
try to set NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION (example NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang3.3) in Android.mk file to the proper toolchain found in ndk-r12.
Android developers documentation:

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION
Define this variable as either 4.9 or 4.8 to select a version of the GCC compiler. Version 4.9 is the default for 64-bit ABIs, and 4.8 is the default for 32-bit ABIs. To select a version of Clang, define this variable as clang3.4, clang3.5, or clang. Specifying clang chooses the most recent version of Clang.
```

Comment: I have changed the path like this:
C:\android-ndk-r12\toolchains\aarch64-linux-android-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64
for every toolchain.

Answer (score 0):

The NDK package you downloaded may have wrong folder name within the llvm toolchain.

Take a look at this path *C:/android-ndk-r12/build//../toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/**windows-x86_64**/bin/clang++.exe*...In my case, the folder was **windows**, I renamed it to match **windows-x86_64** and it worked.